# Continuous Integration for a dynamic changing software

Tags: continuous-integration

We have software applications that undergoes rapids changes quiet frequently - the issue that developers do not write proper unit testing for all changes and commit their code without proper testing due to project pressure and deadline. Also due to changes are many writing unit test case for all scenarios is an additional overhead for project life cycle. As such only pre-coded test cases are executed and build is certified.

Is there any CI methodology that can help in our software industry such that we catch issues with untested code? Which methodology would be best to implement in our case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at FitNesse (http://fitnesse.org), it enables non-developers to write tests. It still requires some knowledge about the code, but at least you'll be less dependent on coders. Note that it's not a replacement for unit tests, it just adds an extra layer of quality control.